# PowerPoint C# - Adding Shape with a Listener

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I am trying to write an Add-In in C# for powerpoint that creates a new Slide and adds TextBox that when clicked performs a certain action. Currently I have gotten an action working where it opens notepad, but I want it to call another function instead.

The current code looks like this :

```
PowerPoint.Shape sendQuestion = slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(Office.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, slideWidth - 200, slideHeight - 50, 200, 50);
sendQuestion.Name = "sendQuestion";
sendQuestion.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter("Send Question");
sendQuestion.ActionSettings[PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Action = PowerPoint.PpActionType.ppActionRunProgram;
sendQuestion.ActionSettings[PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Run = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ThisAddIn_Startup method, initialize the Application_WindowSelectionChange event handler.

```
public void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.WindowSelectionChange += Application_WindowSelectionChange;
}
```

For the event handler, you can have the following code-

```
public void Application_WindowSelectionChange(PowerPoint.Selection sel)
{
    if (sel.Type == PowerPoint.PpSelectionType.ppSelectionShapes)
    {
        if (sel.ShapeRange.Name == "MyTextBox")
        {
         //Perform certain action.
        }
    }
}
```

Also in the ThisAddIn_Shutdown method, you will need to do this-

```
public void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.WindowSelectionChange -= Application_WindowSelectionChange;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. My code is here https://gist.github.com/hiemanshu/a93cdbc7b6d31218f707